# How to display dynamic json data in html using angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

My webservice returns a json data like below.

```
 [{ "Key" : 001,
   "Record" : {"id":"001",
                "name" : "qwerty"}
 },
 { "Key" : 003,
   "Record" : {"id":"003",
                "name" : "asdfg"}
 }]
```

Now I need to display it in a table format. NOrmally in jquery I used to create a table dynamically & will assign a div id to a table, then replace it with dynamically created table.

My component.ts:

```
 export class CatComponent extends Lifecycle {

constructor(
    private $modal: $ModalManagerService,
    private http: HttpClient
) {
    super();
}

_initialize(): void {
        this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/query/aa',{responseType:"json"}).subscribe(
   response => {
     console.log("data :"+response);
     var sample=JSON.stringify(response);
     });
}

}

$("#divv").html(content);
```

Here in angular 6 how should I display?

Comment: You can use `<div id="divv" [innerHTML]='content'></div>`

Comment: You can display array data in a table by using *ngFor in html file.

Comment: Generating table in typescript code is not a good practice.

Comment: @Sujata Chanda You want me use this line in html?

Comment: Yes. If you want to generate the content in ts file then you can create the table using the above html. But as it is Angular, thus it is better to create the entire table in html like in the answers below.

Comment: @MukeshKumar ok thank you but if my requirement is like that, could you please tell me how can we do that?

Comment: can you share the service & ts code please

Comment: @K.Ayoub I have updated ts file in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TS**

```
export class CatComponent extends OnInit{
public data: any;

    constructor(
        private $modal: $ModalManagerService,
        private http: HttpClient

    ) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/query/aa',{responseType:"json"}).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.data = response;
            console.log("data :"+response);
            var sample=JSON.stringify(response);
       });
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor ="let d of data;">
      <td>{{d.Key}}</td>
      <td>{{d.Record.id}}</td>
      <td>{{d.Record.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But if we declare the public data: any; outside the constructor it is working. You are lifesaver. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should put the table layout in your html template and only the logic of getting and assigning the data in your typescript code.
HTML template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Record Id</td>
      <td>Record Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of content">
      <td>{{item.Key}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Record.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Record.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. But still I couln't see my data in the table. Also I got no error.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go u can dynamically load the JSON data in your table using *ngFor Directive*
.component.html

```
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor ="let data of sample;">
      <td>{{data.Key}}</td>
      <td>{{data.Record.id}}</td>
      <td>{{data.Record.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***.component.ts**

```
sample:any= [{ "Key" : "001",
  "Record" : {"id":"001",
               "name" : "qwerty"}
},
{ "Key" : "003",
  "Record" : {"id":"003",
               "name" : "asdfg"}
}];
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. But still I couln't see my data in the table. Also I got no error.

Comment: can you please share your *.ts file ?

Comment: Kumar I have updated my component file. Previously I was trying to generate a table there, But following your example I have just removed that.

Comment: declare your sample variable above the constructor like sample:any; or give the relevant type it will works

Comment: would you be kind enough to tell me? I have declared like sample:any = {}; , I got this error saying, "cannot find a differ supporting object '[object object] of type object.

Comment: Thank you so much, It helped me alot.